# How do I pass a method as a callback/handler parameter to a function?

Tags: rust

The following `executor` function takes a function and calls it with a parameter:

```
fn executor(func: &dyn Fn(String)) {
    // Invoke the callback
    func(String::from("Hello"));
}
```

This code doesn't compile:

```
struct MyStruct {
    the_answer: u32,
}

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn run(&self) {
        executor(&self.printer_method); // <--- Does not compile - rustc(E0615)

        executor(&MyStruct::printer_associated_func); // <--- ...but this does.
    }

    fn printer_method(&self, msg: String) {
        // Access to self.the_answer
        println!(
            "The answer is {}, your message is: {}",
            self.the_answer, msg
        );
    }

    fn printer_associated_func(msg: String) {
        // No access to self.the_answer
        println!("printer: {}", msg);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_struct = MyStruct { the_answer: 42 };
    my_struct.run();
}
```

The full error message:

```
error[E0615]: attempted to take value of method `printer_method` on type `&MyStruct`
  --> src/main.rs:12:24
   |
12 |         executor(&self.printer_method);
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: use parentheses to call the method: `printer_method(...)`
```

How do I pass a *method* (i.e. not an associated function or just a context-less function) to the `executor()` function?

If I'm hitting the language's limits here, which alternatives would I have to access the member variable `self.the_answer` from within a callback?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot obtain a callable pointer to a member function with the syntax you wrote because to be able to call it you need a `self`, so your callable needs to capture `self`, but function pointers always have an empty capture set. That is, if you get a pointer to `MyStruct::printer_method` your function actually accepts two arguments, not one.

To do what you want, you can use a closure that captures your `self`:

```
executor(&|msg| self.printer_method(msg));
```

Note that you actually need a pointer to the closure, because you are passing a `dyn Fn` instead of an `impl Fn`.

Comment: Very good and simple explanation, many thanks!